# PCRE Regular expression : only one matching

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to catch strings which respond to a pattern in a subject string.

Patterns examples: ##name##, ##address##, ##bankAccount##, ...

Subject example:

This is the template with patterns : ##name##

Your bank account is : ##bankAccount##

Your address is : ##address##

With the following regex: `.*(#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}).*`, only the last pattern is matched.

How to capture all the patterns, not just the last or first ?

Comment: Remove `.*`s: `#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but If i remove this part, only the first pattern is matched

Comment: It all depends on what language you are using and what methods you choose. The pattern above will match any substring inside a larger substring as many times as you need provided you are using appropriate methods.

Comment: OK ... I work with PHP ... Initially, I used the simplest pattern, but it does not pass ...

Comment: So, use `preg_match_all`, no big deal.

Comment: Yes, this is the method I use

Comment: So, see my answer and the demo.

Comment: Ok, with preg_match_all, the regex work correctly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `.*` as I mentioned in my comment, and use `preg_match_all`:

```
$re = '~#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}~';
preg_match_all($re, "##name##, ##address##, ##bankAccount##", $m);
print_r($m);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FdEds4)

The `.*#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}.*` matched 0 or more characters other than a newline at first, grabbing the whole *line*, and then backtracked until the last occurrence of `#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}` pattern, and the last `.*` only grabbed the rest of the *line*. Removing the `.*` and using `preg_match_all`, all substrings matching the `#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2}` pattern can be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

*Now that I've formatted your regex properly, the problem shows. A `*` in your regex was hidden since markdown took it to make the text italics.*

---

Your opening `.*` matches greedily as much as it can, only backing up enough to let `(#{2}[a-zA-Z]*#{2})` match. This matches the last pattern found in the line, everything before it having been matched by the `.*`.